# Dot Product With One Dictionary Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, dot-product

I need to calculate the dot product of two keys in a dictionary.

```
res = {'Ben':['5', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '2'...], 
'Moose': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3'...]}
```

I wish to produce something like this. I want to multiply Ben's values with Moose's values.

```
Ans = 31 [5*5 + 0*5 + 0*0 + 0*0 + 1*0 + 4*0 + 2*3...]
```

How can I achieve this with the dictionary? With the list, I can just invoke the np.dot function or write a small loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any keys in dict just using `math` and `zip`. Note this requires python 3.8 or later for [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=math#math.prod):

```py
sum(math.prod(map(int, i)) for i in zip(*res.values()))
```

Comment: I've corrected your code for you, and added a note about the requirement for Python 3.8 or later. Now it's the best answer...

Comment: I am getting this error "AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'prod' "

Comment: @DylandeHoyos you need Python 3.8 to have `math.prod`

Comment: So I use Thonny, which runs Python 3.7, is there anyway to change that to 3.8? Or how would I use this example code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sum` over a list comprehension forming the dot product:

```py
res = {'Ben':['5', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '2'], 
'Moose': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3']}

ans = sum(int(b) * int(m) for b, m in zip(res['Ben'], res['Moose']))
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
31
```

Comment: How would I do this for every res[value] in my dictionary? There are hundreds of keys and values and I need to find the dot product of all of them to determine which ones are the highest. Thiss works if Im trying to specify my keys but is there something I can do for every key?

Comment: @DylandeHoyos take a look at [Conight answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913873/9473764) now that I've edited it. If you're running 3.8 or later it will work for any size of `res`

Answer (score 1):

One way using `zip` and `sum`:

```
sum(int(i) * int(j) for i, j in zip(*res.values()))
```

Output:

```
31
```

In case of dynamic number of keys (and therefore dynamic number of list), you can make a scalable function using `operator.mul` and `functools.reduce`:

```
# Sample data with 3 keys

res3 = {'Ben':['5', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '2'], 
        'Moose': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3'],
        'Chris': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3']}

from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def cummul(iterable):
    return reduce(mul, (int(i) for i in iterable))

sum(cummul(it) for it in zip(*res3.values()))
```

Output:

```
143
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` and iterate over both keys together as follows:

```
sum = 0
for x, y in zip(res['Ben'], res['Moose']):
    sum += int(x) * int(y)
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform something similar to this:

```py
res = {'Ben':['5', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4', '2'], 
'Moose': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3']}

ans = {}
for k, v in res.items():
    if(len(ans.keys())) == 0:
        ans = v
    ans_temp = [v1*v2 for v1, v2 in zip(ans, v)]
    ans = ans_temp

print(sum(ans))
```

This should work for any dict of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0):

using the `numpy` arrays is a good idea and it makes your code shorter, cleaner and more readable:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[int(j) for j in i] for i in list(res.values())])
ans = x.prod(axis=0).sum()
print(ans)
```

no matter how many items are in `res` the above code works fine.